# How to change directoy or Python downloads

Tags: python-2.7

I have this script to download images. But the problem is it saves the files in the same directory with the script. How can i change to to save in another directory? Id love for it to be here G:\Downloads\PICTURES

Here is the script http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2PnuMNnW

I didnt make this, so thanks to the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

As can be found in the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html):

```
import os
os.chdir(/path/to/directory)
```

Change the current working directory to path.

Comment: So i just place os.chdir(G:\Downloads\PICTURES) anywhere in the file?

Comment: You should be able to place it anywhere in the logic before you save the images, although you'll probably have to put your path in quotes: `os.chdir('G:\Downloads\PICTURES')`